# How to get the rank of the last row with specified value?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am working on a dataframe like this one :

```
group | rank |  boolean
-----------------------
1     |1    |  True
1     |2    |  False
1     |3    |  False
2     |1    |  False
2     |2    |  True
2     |3    |  False
```

And I want for each row, to get the last rank in the same group that has a true value in the boolean column :

```
group | rank |  boolean | output
--------------------------------
1     |1    |  True     |1
1     |2    |  False    |1
1     |3    |  False    |1
2     |1    |  False    |null
2     |2    |  True     |2
2     |3    |  False    |2
```

Comment: Shouldn't `null` in output column be `2`?

Comment: No, because he onl wants the rank if the boolean value in the new group is set to True. For group 2, the first entry is false so conditions haven't been met yet

Comment: Is there only one entry with  `True` per group?

Comment: @pythonic833 no there can be more than one

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? Is there anything else that needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this, but this function should do what you want

```
def new_column(df):
    to_iterate_over=df.group.unique()

    g = df.groupby('group')
    new_column_to_add=[]
    for x in to_iterate_over:        
        value='Null'
        for index, row in g.get_group(x).iterrows():
            if row['boolean']==True:
                value=row['rank']
            new_column_to_add.append(value)

    df['output']=new_column_to_add
    return df

df_new=new_column(df)
```

I get the correct output when I run it. I'll look into cleaner implementations though